# Why doesn't onActivityResult() works when I close a second Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm working with an Activity where it shows a AlertDialogFragment with two options, each one opens a new Activity, when I choose the first option I use this code:

```
switch (which){
    case 0:
        //Intent para registrar una compra
        Intent compra=new Intent(getActivity(),CompraActivity.class);
        compra.putExtra("NumeroTarjeta", tarjetasCredito.getNumeroTarjeta());
        compra.putExtra("SaldoDisponible",tarjetasCredito.getSaldoDisponible());
        startActivityForResult(compra, RESULT_CORRECT);
        break;
    case 1:
        //Intent para registrar pago
        Intent pago=new Intent(getActivity(),PagoActivity.class);
        pago.putExtra("NumeroTarjeta", tarjetasCredito.getNumeroTarjeta());
        startActivityForResult(pago, RESULT_CORRECT);
        break;
}
```

RESULT_CORRECT = 1

This works fine, but the problem happens when I set the result in the second activity, the `onActivityResult()`, appears to not work.

what I want to do is launch a method that changes the data of a ListView.
What could be the problem? I've already tried some things but nothing works as expected.

Here is the code from the second activity:

```
public void AgregarCompra(View view) {
    try{
        String lugarCompra=lugar.getText().toString();
        double totalCompra=Double.valueOf(total.getText().toString());
        if(isDataCorrect(lugarCompra,totalCompra)){
            if(SaldoDisponible >= totalCompra){
                DB.SQLFields="NumeroTarjeta,Lugar,Total,Fecha,TipoMovimiento";
                DB.SQLInsert="INSERT INTO "+TABLAS.HISTORIAL_CREDITO+"("+DB.SQLFields+") VALUES ('"+NumeroTarjeta+"','"+lugarCompra+"',"+totalCompra+",'"+ fechaCompra +"','Compra'"+");";
                DB.db.execSQL(DB.SQLInsert);
                DB.SQLUpdate="UPDATE "+TABLAS.TARJETAS_CREDITO+" SET SaldoDisponible="+(SaldoDisponible-totalCompra)+"";
                DB.db.execSQL(DB.SQLUpdate);
                DB.db.close();
                Toast.makeText(this,"Exito al guardar.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                finish();
            }else{
                ErrorDialogFragment errorDialog=new ErrorDialogFragment();
                errorDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"Error");
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Datos vacios.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error de SQLite: "+ex.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error al insertar.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I already send the result in the method before I finished it.
This is the override method in my first activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==RESULT_CORRECT ){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            RefreshList();
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }else{
    }
}
```

Also, is weird that even in the logcat, there's no problem or some error, everything works good for exception of the method when the second activity closes.

Comment: For your information, use only English in your code - it is a good practise, I am not understand variable names =)

Comment: Set breakpoints into `onActivityResult` on a start line, into `AgregarCompra` on 'setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);' line. And check onActivityResult, did it start after AgregarCompra or not

Comment: I know it's a bad practice to mix spanish and english, but sometimes I forgot to code in English only haha, but thanks for the observation. @KirillShalnov

Comment: Ohh, I'm gonna try that, the sad part is that i never used the debugger in Android Studio, but definitely gonna check that. @KirillShalnov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(compra, RESULT_CORRECT);
```

and

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(pago, RESULT_CORRECT);
```

using `getActivity()` ensures that `onActivityResult()` of the activity will be called not the dialog fragment's.

When you don't use `getActivity()` then `onActivityResult` of the fragment is called. Because your fragment is a dialog fragment it will be closed as soon as you click the button on it. So you need to handle the result in calling activity. This is achieved by using `getActivity()`.

Comment: Thanks my friend, this worked very good, now the app enter to the method just only one thing, the method I use to fill the listview run but doesn't change the content, is something weird, should I need to refresh the UI of the activity or there's another way to do that?

Comment: If it doesn't change the content then you should verify the code where you are updating it. Is it getting updated?

Comment: The `RefreshList()` method. You're probably doing something like `mList = new ArrayList<>()`, which makes the mList variable hold the new list, but the `ListView` still remembers the old one. You need to use `mList.clear()` instead.

Comment: Yes it is getting updated, I used the RefreshList method to load the data form the sqlite database and then show the data in the list view, but it would be a better option to post another question about this problem, I'll put the link here. Thanks @Rohit5k2

Comment: Yeah a new question would be better. Also please don't forget to accept it as your answer as it solved the original problem.

Comment: Here's the link of the other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258077/listview-doesnt-update-data