# ListView doesn't update data

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a ListView to show data from a SQLite database file on my phone, when the activity starts, it show the data well, but when I open a second activity, the data has to change according to the operation I do in that activity, to implement this change I used the `onActivityResult()` which have a RefreshList method when everything is correct in the resultCode.
Here's the code example:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==RESULT_CORRECT ){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            RefreshList();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Cancelled Operation",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

These are my global variables:

```
private String LOG_TAG=Credito.class.getSimpleName();

private DatabaseManager DB;

private ListView lstCREDITO;
private List<TarjetasCredito> mTarjetasCredito=new ArrayList<>();

private static TarjetasCredito tarjetasCredito;

private ArrayAdapter<TarjetasCredito> mAdapter;

private static int RESULT_CORRECT=1;
```

This is the RefreshList code that extends from an AsyncTask to do the work in the background and dont blow up the main UI thread:

```
private void RefreshList() {
    GetDataAsync getDataAsync=new GetDataAsync();
    getDataAsync.execute((Void)null);
}

private class GetDataAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
            Cursor cursor=null;
            DB.SQLSelect="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+TABLAS.vistas.visTarjetasCredito+"";
            cursor=DB.db.rawQuery(DB.SQLSelect,null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int cuantos=cursor.getInt(0);
            if(cuantos!=0){
                mTarjetasCredito.clear();
                DB.SQLSelect="SELECT * FROM "+TABLAS.vistas.visTarjetasCredito+"";
                cursor=DB.db.rawQuery(DB.SQLSelect,null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){
                    mTarjetasCredito.add(new TarjetasCredito(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getInt(1),cursor.getDouble(2),cursor.getDouble(3),cursor.getInt(4),cursor.getInt(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7)));
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                DB.db.close();
                cursor.close();
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG,ex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        if(success){
            populateListView();
            creditoCallback();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No hay datos.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void populateListView() {
    mAdapter=new MyListAdapter();
    lstCREDITO.setAdapter(null);
    lstCREDITO.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TarjetasCredito>{
    public MyListAdapter(){
        super(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_view_credito,mTarjetasCredito);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView=convertView;

        if(itemView==null){
            itemView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view_credito,parent,false);
        }

        TarjetasCredito tarjetasCredito=mTarjetasCredito.get(position);

        TextView numero=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNUMEROTARJETA);
        numero.setText(tarjetasCredito.getNumeroTarjeta());

        TextView banco=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtBANCO);
        banco.setText(tarjetasCredito.getNombreBanco());

        TextView saldo=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSALDO);
        saldo.setText(String.valueOf(tarjetasCredito.getSaldoDisponible()));

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it only works when the activity is started but not when the other activity closes and the method of the onActivityResult and the RefreshList works well.
Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure you are updating this table `DB.SQLSelect="SELECT * FROM "+TABLAS.vistas.visTarjetasCredito+"";`?  As per your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257306/why-doesnt-onactivityresult-works-when-i-close-a-second-activity) you are updating `TABLAS.HISTORIAL_CREDITO` table.

Comment: This Select -> DB.SQLSelect="SELECT * FROM "+TABLAS.vistas.visTarjetasCredito+""; is just to retrieve data from a View in the database, to know if there are some data, if there's any, then it clears the List and makes another select to fill the list with the new data that was updated in the other table @Rohit5k2

Comment: You should use a Loader which cares about fetching new data from your DB. Take a look at [this article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) from Alex Lockwood.

Comment: I've been testing the app a few times and now this error comes out:
"attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase", I think that's because I close the connection to the database once the data is retrieved, I think I should re-open the connection once again everytime the RefreshList method is executed.

Comment: I think you are updating different table and loading data from different one.

Comment: Why are you executing a a raw query.. when you can just use a normal query and have less possibility of errors? Also your stactic classes/constants are not following good class naming standards, looks very odd.

Comment: And I was right, that was the solution, just re-open the connection everytime the RefreshList method was executed and everything works correct :), thanks to all of you that helped me, specially @Rohit5k2.

Comment: You're welcome @JoseAndresValenciaAcosta . You forgot to accept my post as answer in the other question

Comment: Because I'm new in SQLite Databases, and don't know too much about querys, I only saw a tutorial where the rawQuery is used to retrieve data, and I decided to use it for this project, but I will read more about SQLite and Android for better practices in the future, but thanks for your observation :) @JoxTraex

Comment: I'm gonna check that tutorial too @JensJensen

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, how do I do that @Rohit5k2, I'm new here too and don't know how to use it property yet, of course I will do it :)

Comment: Please only use android-studio tag if it is specific to the IDE, which your question is not.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that your SQL query is returning data.
Second, you need to update the content of your Adapter. Do this by calling `clear()`; then add the `List` through `addAll()`; then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the ListView.

```
private void populateListView() {
    if(mAdapter==null) {
        mAdapter=new MyListAdapter();
        lstCREDITO.setAdapter(null);
        lstCREDITO.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(mTarjetasCredito);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the data in mTarjetasCredito and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() instead of setting new adapter